# how to resolve this error in selenium using java

Tags: java

```
package excellogin;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class excellogin {
    @Test(dataProvider = "data")
    public static void login(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.synctag.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.id("login_web")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("emailid")).sendKeys("username");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
    }

    @DataProvider (name = "data")
    public Object[][] datasupply() throws Exception{
        File f = new File("D:\\DataProvider_Login\\Book1.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFRow Row = sheet.getRow(0);
        int row = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        int col = Row.getLastCellNum();
        Object[][] testdata1 = new Object[row][col];
        for(int i=0;i<=sheet.getLastRowNum();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<=col;j++){
                testdata1[i][j] = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).toString();
            }
        }
        wb.close();
        return testdata1;       
    }   
}
```

I am getting the below error in my code

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
>       [Utils] [ERROR] [Error] java.lang.NullPointerException at excellogin.excellogin.datasupply(excellogin.java:43)

Help me resolve this error.

> SKIPPED: login
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:49)
>       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:131)
>       at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:706)

Comment: Which one is line 43?

Comment: Also, do you always have data in `getRow(i).getCell(j)`? If you get back null, you can't call `toString()` on it - will need to check it separately.